# How to filter text and then re-open the input window in Roblox?

Tags: roblox, luau

I have followed some YouTube videos and my dad helped me a little, but this is not a language he is very familiar with. He was able to get the inputs working between the local and remote scripts, but he wasn't able to figure out why we never get a success in the remote script for the text filter.

Here is the local script

```
local EditBoothRemote = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("EditBooth")
local editFrame = script.Parent.EditBooth

EditBoothRemote.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.EditBooth.Visible = true

end)

editFrame.Confirm.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.EditBooth.Visible = false
    
    local boothText= editFrame.BoothText.Text
    local imageId = editFrame.Image.Text
    
    EditBoothRemote:FireServer(boothText, imageId)
    
end)
```

Here is the remote

```
local editBoothRemote = game.ReplicatedStorage.EditBooth

editBoothRemote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, boothText, imageId)
    
    if plr.ClaimedBooth.Value ~= nil then
        
        local booth = plr.ClaimedBooth.Value
        local topPart = booth.TopPart
        
        local imageLabel = topPart.SurfaceGui.ImageLabel
        local signText = topPart.SurfaceGui.boothTextLabel
        local filterText
        
        imageLabel.Image = "rbxassetid://" .. imageId .. "&w=420&h=420"
        filterText = boothText
        
        local TextService = game:GetService("TextService")
        local success, errorMessage = pcall(function()
            TextService:FilterStringAsync(filterText)

        end)
        if not success then
            warn("Your sign text " .. filterText .. " is inappropriate, please choose another option")
            editBoothRemote:FireClient(plr)
        else    
            signText.Text = boothText
        end
        
    end
end)
```

We tried to create the filter function in the remote script and have it retrigger the portion of the local script that reactivates the input box. However, we never seem to get anything other than a warn from the text filtering even with a word like flower. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: After a little editing, this looks like a good question. Perhaps someone will see it in due course.